# Finding the elapsed time

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2013, elapsed

This is what I have so far. I am learning structure, and I had to use a structure for the assignment. I don't get what is wrong with my code. When I debug, I get 0 for hour, minute, seconds. Please look at my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct calculate
{
    int hours;
    int minutes;
    int seconds;
};

struct calculate N1;
struct calculate N2;
int resulthr, resultmin, resultsec;

int substract(struct calculate N1, struct calculate N2)
{
    resultsec = N2.seconds - N1.seconds;
    if (resultsec < 0)
    {
        resultsec = 60 + resultsec;
        --N2.minutes;
    }

    resultmin = N2.minutes - N1.minutes;
    if (resultmin < 0)
    {
        resultsec = 60 + resultmin;
        --N2.hours;
    }

    resulthr = N2.hours - N1.hours;
    if (resulthr < 0)
    {
        resulthr = 24 + resultsec;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("Enter two times.(hh:mm:ss) ");
    scanf("%i:%i:%i", &N1.hours, &N1.minutes, &N1.seconds);
    scanf("%i:%i:%i", &N2.hours, &N2.minutes, &N2.seconds);

    int substract(calculate N1, calculate N2);

    printf("The elasped time is %i:%i:%i.\n", resulthr, resultmin, resultsec);

    return 0;
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlYVL.png

Comment: Just use debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call **substract(N1, N2);** instead of **int substract(calculate N1, calculate N2);** in the main function.

You were declaring it, not calling it.

Comment: Thanks. also, I had a mistake on int substract function...                   resultsec = 60 + resultmin should have been resultmin = 60 + resultmin

Answer (score 2):

The line `int substract(calculate N1, calculate N2);` inside your `main` function does not call the previously defined `subtract` method, but it actually declares another function with the same name.
To actually call the method write:

```
   int res = subtract(N1, N2);
```

Afterwards `res` should be 0 and the (global) variables `resulthr,resultmin,resultsec` should have the desired values.

Btw: please read about global and local variables and passing parameters.